# Persistent Volume content gets deleted after StatefulSet / Deployment restart

Tags: kubernetes, persistence, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage

The contents in my Persistent Volume is getting deleted when the StatefulSet or Deployment restarts and new Pods are getting created.

I thought the idea of having Persistent Volume is to have it's content persisted. So I am wondering if there is anything wrong in my configuration.

I have the following PVC:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sftp-pvc
  labels:
    app: sftp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

The PV as such is automatically created and managed. An example of how it looks like created by PVC above is as such:

[image: Persistent Volume example]

And then the following StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sftp-deployment
spec:
  serviceName: sftp-statfulset
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sftp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sftp
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: sftp-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sftp-pvc
      containers:
      - name: sftp
        image: atmoz/sftp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 22
        env:
        - name: SFTP_USERS
          value: "$(SFTP_USERNAME):$(SFTP_PASSWORD):::$(SFTP_ROOT_DIRECTORY)"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ftm-sftp-storage
          mountPath: "/home/$(SFTP_USERNAME)/$(SFTP_ROOT_DIRECTORY)"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

It does not matter if the Resource is StatefulSet or Deployment.

So above is one SFTP server created and deployed on K8s. If I connect to it for example by using FileZilla I can create files or folders and they are being persisted if I log out and log in.

But as soon as the StatefulSet gets restarted and new Pods get created I lose all the files.

How can I make sure that the contents of the Persistent volume stay persistent no matter what is the case?

Comment: I wonder how you confirm the pvc/pv was deleted? I believe that the StatefulSet doesn't remove PVC as default behaviour when a Pod is restarted.

Comment: Change your `reclaimPolicy` to `Retain`

Comment: @hiroyukik PVC / PV as such are not getting deleted, it's content get deleted. the StatefulSet is a SFTP Server and I can check that by connecting to it using a FTP Client like FileZilla and I see that the files I uploaded before restarting of the StatefulSet are not available anymore.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have tried that. the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` is on Persistent Volume and that only means if a PVC gets deleted that the PV doesn't get deleted with it and can be mounted by a new PVC. I have unfortunately a different situation here.

Comment: Seems like everytime pod has started, it creates a `user1` user with mountpoint `/home/user1/user-directory`. May be that's the issue. Have you sure code of your image/pod is correct means data inside your dir wont cleaned by your code or related.

Comment: @dahiya_boy that could be the issue. but how could I resolve that?

Comment: Are you using emptyDir volume? It is a temporary storage space that is created and destroyed with the Pod.

Comment: The other thing I'd check is that the `/home/user1/user-directory` mount point is correct.  If it's not, the mount could be happening correctly but the application could be using a completely different directory inside the temporary container filesystem.

Comment: I have figured out what was the issue. The `mountPath` shouldn't have a path that comprises of environment variables. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I've found out that the `mountPath` value shouldn't be put together by using environment variables. So I've set a fixed value and it worked:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: sftp-storage
  mountPath: "/home/user1/user-directory"
```

Comment: As I remember, same code you are using earlier. What changed you have done??????

Comment: @dahiya_boy In the original question, OP put the `volumeMounts` inside the `containers.env` section, which is incorrect, it should be inside the `containers` section. Here is the K8s API reference for you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#volumes-1